# Using jQuery to build table rows from Ajax response (not with static json data)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, post

I have a javascript and html code of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
    url: "getjson.php", 
    type: "POST",

    success: function (response) 
    {
        console.log(response);
        var trHTML = '';

        $.each(response, function (i, item)
        {   
            trHTML += 
            '<tr><td>' + item.id + 
            '</td><td>' + item.konu + 
            '</td><td>' + item.aciklama + 
            '</td><td>' + item.giris_tarih + 
            '</td><td>' + item.degistirilme_tarih + 
            '</td><td>' + item.ad_soyad + 
            '</td><td>' + item.email + 
            '</td></tr>';            
        });
        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
    }
});
});
</script>


<table id="records_table" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th align="center" width="50">Id</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Konu</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Aciklama</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Giris Tarih</th>
        <th align="center" width="150">Degistirilme Tarih</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Ad Soyad</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Email</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This code doesn't work. It only creates first row but doesn't get json response from getjson.php. 
When I use this with static json data in jsfiddle like this https://jsfiddle.net/tqyn3/761/, it works just as I want. But I want to get data from getjson.php.
How can I convert this to dynamic?

Update:
In debugger console it writes on the above:

```
showjson.php:12 

{"kullanicilar":[{"id":"6","konu":"blood angels","aciklama":"primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"singuinius","email":"warhammer"},{"id":"7","konu":"emperors children","aciklama":"daemon primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"fulgrim","email":"warhammer"},{"id":"8","konu":"night lords","aciklama":"primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"konrad curze","email":"warhammer"},{"id":"9","konu":"grey knights","aciklama":"grand master","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"grand master","email":"warhammer40k"},{"id":"10","konu":"dark angels","aciklama":"primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"lion el jonson","email":"warhammer40k"}]}
```

and it writes in below with red text:

```
jquery-1.11.3.js:577 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in 

{"kullanicilar":[{"id":"6","konu":"blood angels","aciklama":"primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"singuinius","email":"warhammer"},{"id":"7","konu":"emperors children","aciklama":"daemon primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"fulgrim","email":"warhammer"},{"id":"8","konu":"night lords","aciklama":"primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"konrad curze","email":"warhammer"},{"id":"9","konu":"grey knights","aciklama":"grand master","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"grand master","email":"warhammer40k"},{"id":"10","konu":"dark angels","aciklama":"primarch","giris_tarih":"0000-00-00","degistirilme_tarih":"0000-00-00","ad_soyad":"lion el jonson","email":"warhammer40k"}]}
```

Comment: check what is returned by server (console.log(response))

Comment: what is the `getjson.php`?perhaps `getjson` does not return json valid

Comment: getjson.php is another file of getting data from mysql and parsing it to json. When I call only getjsonphp, it returns data without any problem. In my jsfiddle link, its the data returned from getjson.php

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark your question as solved. However, we don't use title hacks to do this here - instead, click the tick mark to the left of your preferred answer, to mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself at last:
Fixed code is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "getjson.php", 
        type: "POST",    
        dataType:"json",   
        success: function (response) 
        {
          var trHTML = '';
          $.each(response, function (key,value) {
             trHTML += 
                '<tr><td>' + value.id + 
                '</td><td>' + value.konu + 
                '</td><td>' + value.aciklama + 
                '</td><td>' + value.giris_tarih + 
                '</td><td>' + value.degistirilme_tarih + 
                '</td><td>' + value.ad_soyad + 
                '</td><td>' + value.email + 
                '</td></tr>';     
          });

            $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
        }   
    });
});
```

I should have added 'dataType: "json",'
And the html is:

```
<table id="records_table" border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th align="center" width="50">Id</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Konu</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Aciklama</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Giris Tarih</th>
        <th align="center" width="150">Degistirilme Tarih</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Ad Soyad</th>
        <th align="center" width="100">Email</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the headers are set to JSON in your PHP. Verify that the response variable has the structure you are expecting as well. It could be an issue with the structure creation in the php. Sometimes json_encode does something different than what you expect.

to console log the repsonse put it here:

```
success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    // the rest of your code
}
```

try:

```
success: function (response) 
{
    console.log(response);
    var trHTML = '';
    var data = response.kullanicilar;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {   
        trHTML += 
        '<tr><td>' + data[i].id + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].konu + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].aciklama + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].giris_tarih + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].degistirilme_tarih + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].ad_soyad + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].email + 
        '</td></tr>';            
    };
    $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
}
```

Comment: json structure is as I wanted. getjson.php works fine if I call it from browser. I just can't create table with dynamic json data.

Comment: what happens when you console.log(response) from getjson.php and from static. is there a difference there?

Comment: Afer which line should I write it? I have tried some lines but none of them returned anything.

Comment: I added it to my answer

Comment: Thanks. I tried that before and called the showjson.php (which is the file that I want to create table and contains the code I wrote above) but nothing happens if I'm doing right. Do I need firebug or something?

Comment: Yes you need some sort of debug tools with a console. all major browsers have one installed by default. f12 will bring it up. then look for something called console. You will see your console log displayed there with the data. Use this to see the difference between the code. If there is one please post both to the question and we can take it from there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81649/discussion-between-gunes-and-corey-young).