# How to Put JSON Data into HTML Table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, html-table

I am using an API to get data for a project, and want to use it in an HTML Table.  The API call:

```
 $.ajax({
headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': '0930de7050d349ceae279be6fabdacd1' },
url: 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/445/leagueTable',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'GET',
}).done(function(response) {
// do something with the response, e.g. isolate the id of a linked resource
var leagueTable = response['standing']
console.log(leagueTable);
});
```

The data is stored in the variable leagueTable.  I want to use the data to present a table with the information recieved from the API call.  How would I use Javascript to do this?

Comment: Do you already have a html code with your table template? Try to be more specific

Comment: check it out :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074532/using-jquery-to-build-table-rows-from-ajax-response-not-with-static-json-data

Comment: You can probably loop through the JSON data and add table rows ("<tr>") to your HTML table but as @ArthurCantarela said... if you already have code please post it so we can help...

Comment: @Ph0b0x How do you loop through a string? Character by character? You know "JSON" is a string, right? You also know that if you _decode_ JSON encoded data you end up with actual native data (objects, arrays, strings, numbers, boolean)?

Comment: You can use JSON.parse()

Comment: @Ph0b0x See what I wrote. You said "loop through JSON". I refer back to my comment. Do you understand that the result of `JSON.parse` is NOT JSON??? A JSON encoded string(!) is the _input_ to that function. But there is no JSON string coming out of it, unless you encoded a JSON string in a JSON string.

Comment: Sorry but i am not following now... your title says “json data” so i supposed you have a json in place and ready to use...

Answer (score 0):

@Mörre here's a more detailed answer of the approach I was trying to suggest.

If you have a string containing JSON formatted data just like this:

```
var jsonStringData = '[{ "Name":"John","LName":"Doe","Occupation":"Henchman" },{ "Name":"Jane","LName":"Doe","Occupation":"Priest" }, { "Name":"Steve","LName":"Rogers","Occupation":"Captain" }]';
```

Then you might be able to convert that string into a JSON object using JSON.parse() like this:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonStringData);
```

Then loop through the data and fill your table like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    //Insert data into HTML table here...
}
```

I put an example JS Fiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pb1hxexL/5/). Hope this helps clarify my suggestion and for you to achieve what you need to do.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with an example using @Jkan282 API call: https://jsfiddle.net/pb1hxexL/6/